# How to effectively debug animation codes

Tags: javascript, animation

```
var lastTime;

function init(){
    lastTime = Date.now();
    main();
}

function main(){
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = now - lastTime;
    update(dt) // main loop
    lastTime = now;
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
```

I'm using above code to build some animation on canvas. `dt` is expected to be around 0.016 because that's 1sec/(60frame/sec), and my code logic is somehow based on this expectation(not necessarily accurate). But everytime when I set a breakpoint and pause the code, `dt` will be very large comparing to the expectation, which makes my code unable to work properly. On summary, my code is on a time basis, but pausing it destorys this basis, although I have to pause to debug it. What a dilemma! What can I do to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success debugging animations that use requestAnimationFrame via Chrome's Timeline.

You basically instruct Timeline to start recording, and when your animation is done you just stop it and analyze the data it has collected.

There is also a *Frames* mode that shows the rendering performance.

For each recorded event you have information about resources consumed, stack trace and others.

It's worth reading Timeline's documentation when dealing with animations and performance issues:

> The Timeline panel lets you record and analyze all the activity in
>   your application as it runs. It's the best place to start
>   investigating perceived performance issues in your application.
>
> https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline